# Get parent object from id that matches objects child array with mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose in NodeJS and I have an id from a child array. I the models are defined like this:

```
var thingSchema = new schema({
    thingId: String,
    smallerThings : [smallerThingsSchema]
});

var smallerThingsSchema = new schema({
    smallerThingId: String,
    name : String,
    anotherName : String
});
```

I have the `smallerThingId`, but I want to get the `thingId`.

Right now I have a for loop that looks like this (pretty ineffective I suppose). Potentially, there could be 100,000 things.

```
//Find all things
thingModel.find({}, null, function (error, things) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
    else {
        //Go through all things  
        for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
            //check if a thing with the array of smaller things matches the id
            for(var j = 0; j<things[i].smallerThings.length; j++){
                if(things[i].smallerThings[j].id === smallerThingId){
                    //return it 
                    return things[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Grateful for any help or where I can look (docs/blog/other) to learn how to handle such scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get document by sub-document id you can use following code:

```
thingModel.find({"smallerThings.smallerThingId":smallerThingId}, null, function (error, things) {

});
```

This will return document having "smallerThingId".

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoose find like:

```
thingModel.find({"things.smallerThings.id": smallerThingId }, null, function (error, things) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
    else {
        //do what you need
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work. There is nothing called "things" as you state.